# DC for removing persistent Bleed after Administer First Aid?

Tags: damage, healing, pathfinder-2e

The rules for ending [persistent damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=29) seem fairly straightforward (if more brutal than many other iterations). There is the ability to use the Activity [Administer First Aid](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=54) to allow for additional checks specifically for persistent bleed.

However, the Activity only says

> Stop Bleeding Attempt a Medicine check on a creature that is taking persistent bleed damage, giving them a chance to make another flat check to remove the persistent damage. The DC is usually the DC of the effect that caused the bleed.

and in persistent it includes

> Reduce the DC of the flat check to 10 for a particularly appropriate type of help, such as dousing you in water to put out flames.

Is there any guidance that suggests Administer First Aid has its resulting Flat check DC reduced? Or should it be at the standard DC/up to the GM?

Comment: I believe that "The GM decides how your help works" like written in the Persistent Damage rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually the rules already specify that administer first aid do provides you a second check and lower flat check DC for bleed persistent damage (or ends entirely the condition).

> [...]For example, you might try to smother a flame, wash off acid, or **use Medicine to Administer First Aid to stanch bleeding.** This allows you to attempt an extra flat check immediately.

The part about the lowered dc are ***guidelines*** so every GM should have *very good motivation* to ignore them in my opinion.
The examples talk by themselves:

> Reduce the DC of the flat check to 10 for a particularly appropriate type of help, such as dousing you in water to put out flames.
>
> Automatically end the condition due to the type of help, such as healing that restores you to your maximum HP to end persistent bleed damage, or submerging yourself in a lake to end persistent fire damage.

As a side note I think the lowered DC only applies to this extra flat check (the one your ally is providing you) and not the normal one...but there is no specific indication about this.